# add channels couchbase with Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, couchbase, channel, couchbase-lite

How can I add channels to my PULL and PUSH replications with Xamarin PLC (C#)? And to the documents?

I tried to write something and set channels, but still not working.
The documents created after that instruction hadn't got any channels.

Here my code:

```
{       
        if (Manager.SharedInstance.GetDatabase(DatabaseName) == null)
            return;

        IAuthenticator auth = 
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Username) 
            ? null
            : AuthenticatorFactory.CreateBasicAuthenticator(Username, Password);


        pull = Manager.SharedInstance.GetDatabase(DatabaseName).CreatePullReplication(RemoteSyncUrl);
        if(auth != null)
        {
            pull.Authenticator = auth;
        }

        push = Manager.SharedInstance.GetDatabase(DatabaseName).CreatePushReplication(RemoteSyncUrl);
        if(auth != null)
        {
            push.Authenticator = auth;
        }

        pull.Continuous = true;
        push.Continuous = true;

        pull.Changed += ReplicationProgress;
        push.Changed += ReplicationProgress;

        //Set channels
        List<string> channels = new List<string>();
        channels.Add("channel");

        // I had try to do that but not working,
        // the documents created after that hadn't got the channels 
        pull.Channels = channels;
        push.Channels = channels;

        pull.Start();
        push.Start();
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Riccardo

Comment: Channels are not created via the client, they are created via the sync function on your sync gateway instance.  What you are doing there is *querying* the channels that you haven't created yet.